# Laravel: saving a serialized copy of my model for history

Tags: php, events, laravel-5, model

I need to manage record history for a specific model(s).
So following the example here (https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#events) I did something like this in my AppServiceProvider.php file:

```
use App\SourceModel;
use App\History;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        SourceModel::saving(function ($source) {
            $his= new History();
            $his->record = $source->toJson();
            $his->user_id = Auth::User()->id;
            $his->saved_id = $source->id;
            $his->saved_type = 'App\SourceModel';
            $his->save();
        });
    }

...
```

The problem is in this way Auth::User() returns NULL...

How can I solve this problem? is there a way to make Auth working in appserviceprovider or should i move my saving event somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this closure is called when the model is saving, I would expect this to work assuming there is an authenticated user.

I was able to confirm this does work using tinker:

```
>>> App\User::saving(function ($user) { echo "AUTH USER ID: " . Auth::user()->id; });
=> null
>>> Auth::login(App\User::find(1));
=> null
>>> App\User::find(1)->save();
AUTH USER ID: 1⏎
=> true
```

Therefore, I would say that if `Auth::user()` returns `null`, this model was saved without an authenticated user and if that can happen you need to add a check:

```
    SourceModel::saving(function ($source) {
        $his= new History();
        $his->record = $source->toJson();
        $his->user_id = (Auth::check()) ? Auth::User()->id : 0;
        $his->saved_id = $source->id;
        $his->saved_type = 'App\SourceModel';
        $his->save();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the right place to listen model events are EventServiceProvider ( App\Providers\EventServiceProvider ).

Simply move your code to "boot" method in EventServiceProvider and you are done.

```
<?php
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event;
use App\SourceModel;
use App\History;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The event listener mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $listen = [
        'App\Events\SomeEvent' => [
            'App\Listeners\EventListener',
        ],
    ];
    /**
     * Register any events for your application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        //

        SourceModel::saving(function ($source) {
            $his= new History();
            $his->record = $source->toJson();
            $his->user_id = Auth::User()->id;
            $his->saved_id = $source->id;
            $his->saved_type = 'App\SourceModel';
            $his->save();
        });
    }
}
```

Note: you can include facades like this: "use \Auth"

Comment: Why would this change address anything if the Auth::user() is returning null?  The event is initialized fine if they are receiving a problem from the event on the model save.

Comment: Changing address is just a tip

Comment: Event listeners don't need to be added in the EventServiceProvider, they can be added anywhere that makes sense.  Usually in the related service provider, but can be anywhere that is only called once.  (If the listener is called multiple times, the callback will be performed multiple times)